# HttpContext.Current.Session - NullReferenceException Session-property is always null

Tags: c#, session, null

I've got an C#-WebService in VS2015. It's about the following method:

```
    [Route("api/tfsdata/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    [WebMethod(enableSession : true)]
    public void login()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Session: " + HttpContext.Current.Session);
    }
```

The output on the console is just "Session: " and I can see in the debugger, that the Session-object is null. So everytime, I'm using this object, I get a NullReferenceException. I also added a sessionState-Tag to the Web.config, like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <sessionState
        mode="InProc"
        cookieless="false"
        timeout="200"
    />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I already used Google for several times, and read the articles here too, but I can't figure out, what's the problem. And I also tried to write the enableSessions Attribute as: `[WebMethod(EnableSessions = true)]`

Comment: Where and how do you set the session?

Comment: I use it like: HttpContext.Current.Session["data"] = "dataString";

Comment: Then call it in the same way: Debug.WriteLine("Session: " + HttpContext.Current.Session["data"]);

Comment: Like I already said: the Sessions-object ist completely null.

Comment: As you see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx you cannot set this property.

Comment: Set it like Session["FirstName"] = firstName;

Comment: I cant use it like that, VS says he cant find the definition of "Session"

Comment: btw I'm not trying to set the whole property. I'm trying to get it, so I can use it. I don't even have an Session-object to set. That's the whole point.